# Confusion about JWE token

Tags: encryption, jwt

I have read about this stateless session token JWT that encapsulates user session information in a single Base64 encoded URL string including JSON data in it. The format I have understood the most was the JWS (JSON Web Signature) format, and it works indeed as follow: Client requests the server to be authenticated given some user credentials (say unique username and password). The Server then checks against the validity of these crendetials, and if everything is ok it will generate a JW token signed with a private key and send it back to the user for future authorized operations. And up to this point everything was clear to me.

Then I heard about the other token type: JWE (JSON Web Encryption) token. You would use this type of token to also provide confidentiality between the two parties by encrypting the payload with a private key. You would use this type of token to send information that you do not want to be read by other parties.

Now the confusion here is the following: **To encrypt the payload you need a pair of public and private keys.**

So how and when in a practical web application should I generate these keys? In the login step when authenticating the user? Who should store these keys? The server? The client? Both? and what about when I want to authorize the user to use specific APIs? Should I just store the JWE token in the client side and use it as is to use the various APIs?

Everything is clear if this encryption layer was not added, like I understand how to operate with that scenario. But when these public/private keys appeared for generating such JWE token, confusion now arised!